# What is the meaning of the descriptivism tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I never noticed the **[descriptivism tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/descriptivism/)** until today, when it *was** used for **[this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56491/corner-shop-white-bread-metaphor)** which is now closed. At present, there are ten uses of the descriptivism tag on the site, including the closed question. I considered drafting a wiki entry for it, but I truly don't know what the intended usage is. **Might anyone provide some some suggestions about how this tag should be used?**

SE engine's spell-checker red lines *descriptivism*. This doesn't mean that the tag is incorrect or bad! I mention the red lining only to emphasize that the word, or term, is somewhat unusual for a tag in the context of this site.

*The closed question no longer has the same tags. The *descriptivism* tag count equals nine.

Comment: The only reference to *descriptivism* was this question: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/490/where-and-how-would-it-be-appropriate-to-discuss-descriptivism-vs-prescriptivism which is indeed VERY meta. It seemed like there was agreement that the subject of the question was a discussion type topic. I read all the answers and comments but it did not help me understand how the tag should actually be used on the main site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see the point of the *descriptivism* tag on ELU. Rather ironically, the tag itself has no description, but I assume whoever created it was thinking of [descriptive linguistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description) *- the work of objectively analyzing and describing how language is spoken*.

I think it's about as much use as having a tag called *usage* (or one called *English*, come to that).

Comment: @Feral Oink: I think it was only there because Seamus asked [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/descriptivism-and-widespread-misspelling) back in Oct '10 and *only* had that tag on it. I've just re-tagged it to "word-choice" and knocked "descriptivism" off the few others that had it. If anyone's unhappy they can put it back and we'll argue about it!

Comment: Yay! Thank you very much for addressing that matter. I am going to delete my earlier comment, as anti-fragility is not pertinent to descriptivism, and will just confuse anyone who sees it after the fact.